# second vc is smaller that the initial vc

Tags: swift, ipad, uiviewcontroller, transition, updates

I got this problem on iPad after update yesterday: if I load the second view controller, it appears smaller that the initial one (see photos below). Interesting, that is happening only since my update to the new iOS on iPad. There is no such problem on iPhone: the both VCs have there the same size.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class StartVC: UIViewController, ButtonDelegate {


   var width = CGFloat()
   var height = CGFloat()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    width = view.frame.width
    height = view.frame.height

    setTestBtn()


    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple

}

func setTestBtn(){

    let a = Button(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: width*0.2, height: width*0.2))
    a.center = CGPoint(x: width*0.5, y: height*0.5)
    a.backgroundColor = .cyan
    a.delegate = self
    a.setLabel()
    a.label.text = "Go to the MainVC"
    view.addSubview(a)
}

func buttonClicked(sender: Button) {

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainVC") as! MainVC
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 2
    transition.type = CATransitionType.push
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromRight
    view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

    vc.view.frame = view.bounds

    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


       print("# ViewController func buttonClicked() OK!")

   }




import UIKit

class MainVC: UIViewController, ButtonDelegate {

var width = CGFloat()
var height = CGFloat()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    width = view.frame.width
    height = view.frame.height

    setTestBtn()

    view.backgroundColor = .red


}

func setTestBtn(){

    let a = Button(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: width*0.2, height: width*0.2))
    a.center = CGPoint(x: width*0.5, y: height*0.5)
    a.backgroundColor = .orange
    a.delegate = self
    a.setLabel()
    a.label.text = "Go to the StartVC"
    view.addSubview(a)
}

func buttonClicked(sender: Button) {

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "startVC") as! StartVC
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 2
    transition.type = CATransitionType.push
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromRight
    view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

    vc.view.frame = view.bounds

    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

       print("# ViewController func buttonClicked() OK!")

   }


}
```

[image: Initial View Controller iPad]
[image: Second View Controller iPad]
[image: Initial View Controller iPhone]
[image: Second View Controller iPhone]

Comment: move your code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and see what happens.

Comment: Mumtaz, I tried it now: the same result.

Comment: I believe you're on iOS 13?

Comment: yep, iPadOS 13.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the release of iOS 13, the modal presentation style of View Controllers is chosen automatically by the system by default.

If you wish to counter this effect, this can help you.

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that was a problem. Thank you so much.